# Using Beautifulsoup to get a tags and attriibutes of these a tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I just started using beautifulsoup and am stuck on an issue regarding getting attributes of tags inside other tags. I am using the whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/ for practice. What I'm trying to do right now is just get all the links on this page and append them to an empty list. This is my code right now:

```
    result = requests.get("https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/")

    src = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

    urls = []

    for h2_tags in soup.find_all('h2'):
        a_tag = h2_tags.find('a')
        urls.append(a_tag.attr['href']) # This is where I get the NoneType error
```

This code returns the <a tags, but the first and last 3 tags it returns are 'None' and because of this, get a type error when trying to access the attributes to get the href for these <a tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that some `<h2>` tags don't contain `<a>` tags. So you have to check for that alternative. Or just select all `<a>` tags that are under `<h2>` using CSS selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = requests.get("https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/")

src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

urls = []

for a_tag in soup.select('h2 a'):    # <-- select <A> tags that are under <H2> tags
    urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])

print(*urls, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/10/statement-by-nsc-spokesperson-emily-horne-on-national-security-advisor-jake-sullivan-leading-the-first-virtual-meeting-of-the-u-s-israel-strategic-consultative-group/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2021/03/09/press-briefing-by-press-secretary-jen-psaki-and-deputy-director-of-the-national-economic-council-bharat-ramamurti-march-9-2021/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/09/readout-of-the-white-houses-meeting-with-climate-finance-leaders/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/09/readout-of-vice-president-kamala-harris-call-with-prime-minister-erna-solberg-of-norway/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/09/nomination-sent-to-the-senate-3/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/09/president-biden-announces-key-hire-for-the-office-of-management-and-budget/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/speeches-remarks/2021/03/09/remarks-by-president-biden-during-tour-of-w-s-jenks-son/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/09/president-joseph-r-biden-jr-approves-louisiana-disaster-declaration/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/09/statement-by-president-joe-biden-on-the-house-taking-up-the-pro-act/
https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/09/white-house-announces-additional-staff/
```